# Ordenar la columna total de manera ascendente o descendente

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Necesito la columna total de manera ascendente o descendente que obtengo del metodo subtotalRow donde obtengo el total por fila según el filtro

```
    <table class="table card-table table-vcenter text-nowrap table-hover">
    
                        <thead>
    
                        <tr>
                            <th style="background-color: white">Razón Social</th>
                            <template v-for="(row, key) in filterLista">
                                <template v-for="(meses, ano) in row">
                                    <template v-for="(total_mes, mes) in meses">
                                        <th style="background-color: white">{{ printMonth(mes) }}  {{ ano  }}</th>
                                    </template>
                                </template>
                            </template>
                            <th style="background-color: white" @click="sortedList">Totales</th>
                        </tr>
    
                        </thead>
    
                        <tbody>
                        <template v-for="(raz_soc, rut) in entidades">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="background-color: white">{{ printName(rut) }}</td>
                                <template v-for="row in sortedList">
                                    <template v-for="(meses, ano) in row">
                                        <template v-for="(total_mes, mes) in meses">
                                            <td v-if="pendientes[ano][mes]">{{  total_mes[rut] ? Intl.NumberFormat('es-ES').format(total_mes[rut]) : 0 }}</td>
                                        </template>
                                    </template>
                                </template>
                           
                                <td>{{ subtotalRow(rut) }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </template>
    
                        </tbody>
    
                        <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="background-color: #f5f5f5"></td>
    
    
                        </tr>
                        </tfoot>
    
                    </table>



new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            totalMensual: {
                2017: { 8: { 99526550: 8402118 }, 12: { 99526550: 16805365 } },
        2018: {
          1: { 99526550: 3380427 },
          2: { 99526550: 3383808 },
          6: { 76467560: 1450000 },
          7: { 76675405: 1741365 },
          8: { 76675405: 11577539 },
          9: { 96777810: 2588845 },
          10: { 76898325: 3000000 },
          12: { 76035258: 14868336 }
        },
        2019: {
          2: { 76035258: 1594755 },
          3: { 76675405: 11707602 },
          5: { 79587210: 9460500 },
          9: { 10836904: 6080000 },
          10: { 76849049: 11900000 },
          11: { 76914652: 18216520 },
          12: { 76122571: 9779550 }
        },
        2020: {
          2: { 76122564: 658878, 76675405: 784312 },
          3: { 76122571: 6746300, 77418580: 37901500 },
          4: { 76860599: 12288093 },
          8: { 76122571: 3519040, 76829879: 8986547, 76985375: 7139000 },
          11: { 76833156: 0, 79587210: -342845469, 96935140: 0 },
          12: {
            76131794: 99960000,
            76833156: 43282120,
            77078359: 54621000,
            77241295: 110610500,
            77612130: 53818420,
            79587210: 534178302,
            92176000: 6156500,
            96935140: 7812350
          }
        }
            },
            filterLista: [],
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.filterLista = Object.entries(this.totalMensual).map(([key, value]) => ({
            [key]: value
        }))
    },
    computed: {
        sortedList() {
            return this.filterLista.sort((a, b) => Object.keys(a)[0] - Object.keys(b)[0])
        }
    },

     methods: {
            subtotalRow(index) {
                let sum = 0;
                this.sortedList.map((anio, value) => {
                    for(const meses in anio){
                        for (const mes in anio[meses]) {
                           // console.log(anio[meses][mes])
                            for (const rut in anio[meses][mes]){
                                if (rut == index){
                                    sum = sum + anio[meses][mes][rut];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
               return Intl.NumberFormat('es-ES').format(sum)
            },
            printName(rut){
                return this.entidades[rut]
            },
            printMonth(mesMumber){
                if (mesMumber == 1){
                    return "Enero"
                } else if (mesMumber == 2){
                    return "Febrero"
                } else if (mesMumber == 3){
                    return "Marzo"
                } else if (mesMumber == 4){
                    return "Abril"
                } else if (mesMumber == 5){
                    return "Mayo"
                } else if (mesMumber == 6){
                    return "Junio"
                } else if (mesMumber == 7){
                    return "Julio"
                } else if (mesMumber == 8){
                    return "Agosto"
                } else if (mesMumber == 9){
                    return "Septiembre"
                } else if (mesMumber == 10){
                    return "Octubre"
                } else if (mesMumber == 11){
                    return "Noviembre"
                } else if (mesMumber == 12){
                    return "Diciembre"
                }
            }
        }

})
```

Comment: Y cual seria el problema?

Comment: El problemas es que uso sort en el método computado y me genera un loop infinito

Comment: @gbianchi Entonces use una libreria me realizar el sorting de la columna total cuando doy click en ella pero no toma en cuenta los montos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dudo que el problema sea por un ciclo infinito, sino que no es posible ordenar objetos en la forma que lo estás intentando, además de que no has sumado todavía los totales por mes; tal vez si conviertes los objetos en cadena puedas realizar el `.sort()`, pero dudo que los resultados sean los esperados.

Te sugiero crear un arreglo que sí pueda ordenarse, con una estructura como esta:

```
[
    {
        year: año,
        month: mes,
        ruts: [
            { rut: rut1, value: valor1 }
            { rut: rut2, value: valor2 }
            { rut: rutX, value: valorX }
        ],
        total: suma de todos los ruts del mes
    }
]
```

Por supuesto, esto va a implicar cambios en la vista, pero supongo que será fácil adaptarla después de ver el resultado en consola.

```js
let totalMensual = {
        2017: { 8: { 99526550: 8402118 }, 12: { 99526550: 16805365 } },
        2018: {
          1: { 99526550: 3380427 },
          2: { 99526550: 3383808 },
          6: { 76467560: 1450000 },
          7: { 76675405: 1741365 },
          8: { 76675405: 11577539 },
          9: { 96777810: 2588845 },
          10: { 76898325: 3000000 },
          12: { 76035258: 14868336 }
        },
        2019: {
          2: { 76035258: 1594755 },
          3: { 76675405: 11707602 },
          5: { 79587210: 9460500 },
          9: { 10836904: 6080000 },
          10: { 76849049: 11900000 },
          11: { 76914652: 18216520 },
          12: { 76122571: 9779550 }
        },
        2020: {
          2: { 76122564: 658878, 76675405: 784312 },
          3: { 76122571: 6746300, 77418580: 37901500 },
          4: { 76860599: 12288093 },
          8: { 76122571: 3519040, 76829879: 8986547, 76985375: 7139000 },
          11: { 76833156: 0, 79587210: -342845469, 96935140: 0 },
          12: {
            76131794: 99960000,
            76833156: 43282120,
            77078359: 54621000,
            77241295: 110610500,
            77612130: 53818420,
            79587210: 534178302,
            92176000: 6156500,
            96935140: 7812350
          }
        }
            };
let filterLista = [];

// Recorrer por años
Object.keys(totalMensual).forEach(year => {
    // Recorrer meses en cada año
    Object.keys(totalMensual[year]).forEach(month => {
        // Se necesita el índice para actualizar otras propiedades
        let index = filterLista.length;
        // Insertar objeto con estructura sugerida y valores por defecto
        filterLista.push({
            year: year,
            month: month,
            ruts: [],
            total: 0
        });
        // Recorrer cada rut para agregarlo al arreglo interno y calcular total por mes
        Object.keys(totalMensual[year][month]).forEach(rut => {
            filterLista[index].ruts.push({
                rut: rut,
                value: totalMensual[year][month][rut]
            });
            filterLista[index].total += totalMensual[year][month][rut];
        });
    });
});

// Ya tienes un arreglo con totales y que se puede ordenar
let sorted = [...filterLista].sort((a, b) => a.total - b.total);
console.log(sorted);
```

El arreglo se ordena de forma ascendente, pero puedes invertirlo fácilmente con [.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) para tenerlo en descendente.

Se [desestructura](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) el arreglo al ordenar para no modificar el original, porque [.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) toma el arreglo por referencia y no por valor.

> El método sort() ordena los elementos de un arreglo (array) **localmente** y devuelve el arreglo ordenado.

Es más fácil de entender con un ejemplo:

```js
let frutas = ['guindas', 'manzanas', 'bananas'];
let frutas2 = ['guindas', 'manzanas', 'bananas'];

// Sin desesctructurar también se modifica el original
let frutas3 = frutas.sort();
console.log(frutas, frutas3);

// Desestructurando se mantiene el original sin cambios
let frutas4 = [...frutas2].sort();
console.log(frutas2, frutas4);
```

Comment: He probado el código de la siguiente manera y se me queda trabado ejecutando infinitamente el loop

Comment: He montado el ciclo forEach en mounted de vue

Comment: De acuerdo al [ciclo de vida de vue](https://codingpotions.com/vue-ciclo-vida), creo que deberías generar `filterLista` en `created:`, antes de generar una salida.

Comment: No me funciona se me cuelga el navegador. al tratar de consultar esa data

Comment: Creo que estoy haciendo algo mal.

Comment: Cambia completamente la estructura de los datos, por lo que debes actualizar las plantillas y depende mucho de cómo quieres mostrar. Edita la pregunta para poner tu código actualizado, así podemos tratar de ver dónde está el error.